# Java - parentheses and assignment

Tags: java, grouping, parentheses, operator-precedence

The code:

```
int r=1;
System.out.println(r + (r=2));
```

The output is: 3. But I expected 4 because I thought the code inside the parentheses is executed first?

Comment: Executed first? No, parentheses only affect associativity. Java always evaluate operands from left to right.

Comment: Why would you expect 4? just curious...

Comment: Thx all... My presumption that code in parentheses is executed first was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Official Docs on Operators says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

> All binary operators except for the assignment operators are evaluated from left to right; assignment operators are evaluated right to left.

So  `+` is evaluated `left-to-right`,where as assignment operators are evaluated `right to left.`

Answer (score 4):

Use this if you want 4

```
int r=1;
System.out.println((r=2) + r); // execute + is left-to-right
```

Comment: Could you explain, how it is evaluating to `4`? I couldn't understand how it is working. Based on my understanding, I am assuming it would work like : `((r=2) + r) => ( 2 + r ) => (2 + 1) = 3`. Please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: @John `r=2` assigns 2 to `r`. So the next time `r` is used, its value is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Associativity of `+` is left-to-right , and the value of the expression `(r=2)` is `2`.

Refer [JLS 15.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

> The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.
>
> If the operator is a compound-assignment operator (§15.26.2), then evaluation of the left-hand operand includes both remembering the variable that the left-hand operand denotes and fetching and saving that variable's value for use in the implied binary operation.
>
> If evaluation of the left-hand operand of a binary operator completes abruptly, no part of the right-hand operand appears to have been evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

it's like this

```
(r + (r=2))
(1 + (r=2))
(1 + (2))
(3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of statement `r=2` is 2. Nested expressions between brackets are processed first though.

For instance:

```
int r=2;
System.out.println(r * (r=2 + 1));
```

Output:

```
6
```

Why? Because `r = 2 + 1` returns `3`.

Same as:

```
int r=2;
System.out.println(r * (2 + 1));
```

Output still `6` because `(2 + 1)` is evaluated before multiplication.