# Why System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+s1==s2); prints "false" as the output instead of printing "hey s1==s2:false"

Tags: java, string

I have written the following java code:

```
String s1 = new String("shan");
String s2 = new String("shan");
String s3="shan";
String s4="shan";
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+s1==s2);
System.out.println("s3==s4:"+s3==s4);
System.out.println("s1.equals(s2): "+s1.equals(s2));
System.out.println("s3.equals(s4): "+s3.equals(s4));
System.out.println("s1==s3: "+s1==s3);
System.out.println("s1.equals(s3): "+s1.equals(s3));
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+true);
```

The output:

```
false
false
s1.equals(s2): true
s3.equals(s4): true
false
s1.equals(s3): true
hey s1==s2:true
```

Why does line #5 result in just "false" as the output instead of "hey s1==s2:false"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Line5: System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+s1==s2);
```

Because of the operator precedence `"hey s1==s2:"+s1` resolving first and then comparing to **s2** which leads to false.

Give the highest precedence to resolve it to correct. Parenthesis have the highest precedence.

```
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+(s1==s2));
```

Comment: What is happening in line #11?  Why System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+true); is resulting in hey s1==s2:true as the output. Why no evaluation is happening here?

Comment: @ShanthaD What you are expecting there ?

Comment: Neither "hey s1==s2:"+s1 nor s2 are Boolean. But still it evaluated "hey s1==s2:"+s1==s2 to false. In the same way, it would have evaluated "hey s1==s2:"+true to false instead of evaluating it to s1==s2:true right?

Comment: @ShanthaD It is because, the operator + evaluates from left to right. Look at here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808093/java-parentheses-and-assignment  That might exaplain.

Comment: yeah, I agree that operator + evaluates from left to right. But  Ex:             String x="hey s1==s2:"+s1;
  String y=s2;
  System.out.println("value of x is: "+x);
  System.out.println("value of y is: "+y);
  System.out.println(x==y);                      Output:                                                          value of x is: hey s1==s2:shan
value of y is: shan
false                                                               How the value of "hey s1==s2:shan" == "shan" resulted in false?

Comment: Understood it finally. :) "hey s1==s2:"+s1 (We are concatenating 2 strings here) resulted in new string "hey s1==s2:shan". And we are comparing that string with "shan". Since both are different strings, comparison of those strings resulted in false.

Comment: @ShanthaD Hmm... wonna throw some party ;) Great to hear. Happy coding.

Answer (score 7):

```
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+s1==s2)
```

evaluates `("hey s1==s2:"+s1)==s2`, which is `false`

That's why false is printed.

The reason for this behavior is that the `+` operator has a higher [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) than the "==" operator.

The following would print what you expected :

```
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+(s1==s2))
```

Answer (score 1):

To comapre strings you have to call `s1.equals(s2)`. the result is `true`. `==` compares the pointer to the strings and that sare not the same.

Comment: That doesn't explain the output (why the "hey", etc. is missing).

Answer (score 0):

use brackets for surround separate operations in statement.

use

```
System.out.println("hey s1==s2:"+(s1==s2));
```